# tkinter listbox not updating with trace()

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I'm trying to make a searchbox in tkinter where you try stuff into the entry box and in a listbox below that it shows everything in a certain list that contains what you typed. I got the initial code from [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/22nhwe/dynamic_search_barfilter_with_tkinter/)

However since I don't really understand classes I decided to shorten it to this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def update_list(*args):
    search_term = search_var.get()

    # Just a generic list to populate the listbox
    lbox_list = ['Adam', 'Lucy', 'Barry', 'Bob',
                 'James', 'Frank', 'Susan', 'Amanda', 'Christie']

    lbox.delete(0, END)

    for item in lbox_list:
        if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
            lbox.insert(END, item)


# searchbar
search_var = StringVar()
search_var.trace("w", update_list)
entry = Entry(root,textvariable=search_var, width=13)
lbox = Listbox(root, width=45, height=15)
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=3)
lbox.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=20, padx=2, pady=3)
update_list()

root.mainloop()
```

This code works just fine, so I decided to apply it to my actual program, which is where I ran into issues.

```
def main():
    # searchbar
    search_var = StringVar()
    entry = Entry(root,textvariable=search_var, width=13)
    lbox = Listbox(root, width=40, height=15)
    entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=3)
    lbox.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=2, pady=3)
    search_var.trace("w", update_list)
    update_list(search_var,lbox)
def update_list(search_var,lbox):
    search_term = search_var.get()
    print(search_term)

    # Just a generic list to populate the listbox
    lbox_list = ['Adam', 'Lucy', 'Barry', 'Bob',
                 'James', 'Frank', 'Susan', 'Amanda', 'Christie']

    lbox.delete(0, END)

    for item in lbox_list:
        if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
            lbox.insert(END, item)

# main window (menu)
root = Tk()
main()
root.mainloop()
```

The issue I run into is that the listbox doesn't update. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats difference between both?  and that to you gave it a name as `main` which would be called only once. You are making it more complex than first one

Comment: @Karthik I need to be able to execute the content of main() again in the future, which is why I made it a function. The issue arises from having the searchbar created in a function, however I'm not sure why and I'm not sure how to fix it since I need it inside the function.

Comment: Try changing `search_var.trace("w", update_list)` to `search_var.trace("w", lambda *args: update_list(search_var, lbox))`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you that worked perfectly! Mind explaining how that works or linking a website that does?

Comment: I guess that it is most likely that `search_var` is a local variable inside `main()` function.  So using `search_var.trace("w", update_list)` does not explicitly show that `search_var` is being referenced after `main()` returns and it may be garbage collected.  However using `search_var.trace("w", lambda *args: update_list(search_var, lbox))` explicitly shows that `search_var` is still be referenced after `main()` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `search_var` was expiring when the `main` function completed so, whatever updates you were telling it to do also expired. The reason why @acw1668 solution worked is because the `lambda` is keeping the reference alive. This could have also been accomplished with the `global` keyword, although I like acw1668's approach a bit more as it gives a modicum of encapsulation. However, abusing `lambda` just to keep arbitrary references alive is not a good design choice. Also, if you were doing this in a loop with multiple recurring references, as that `lambda` currently stands, only the very last reference would be kept alive.

Here is what the global approach would have looked like

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def main():
    global search_var
    search_var = StringVar()
    
    entry = Entry(root, textvariable=search_var, width=13)
    entry.grid(padx=2, pady=3)

    global lbox
    lbox = Listbox(root, width=40, height=15)
    lbox.grid(padx=2, pady=3)

    search_var.trace("w", update_list)
    update_list(lbox)    
    
    
def update_list(*args):
    search_term = search_var.get()

    lbox_list = ['Adam', 'Lucy', 'Barry', 'Bob',
                 'James', 'Frank', 'Susan', 'Amanda', 'Christie']

    lbox.delete(0, END)
    
    for item in lbox_list:
        if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
            lbox.insert(END, item)

main() 
root.mainloop()
```

I noticed that you said that you are doing it this way because you need to get this display again in the future. That means that you intend to get rid of this display at some point. How do you intend to do that when you have no references to any of the widgets you just made? Your design is very flawed and that `lambda` isn't helping you make it better. Maybe you would like to consider a design that actually gives you a modicum of control.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def search_frame(row=0, column=0):
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.grid(row=row, column=column)
    
    def update_list(*args):
        search_term = entry.var.get()

        lbox_list = ['Adam', 'Lucy', 'Barry', 'Bob',
                     'James', 'Frank', 'Susan', 'Amanda', 'Christie']

        lbox.delete(0, tk.END)
    
        for item in lbox_list:
            if search_term.lower() in item.lower():
                lbox.insert(tk.END, item)
                
    entry     = tk.Entry(frame, width=13)
    entry.var = tk.StringVar()
    entry.var.trace("w", update_list)
    entry.configure(textvariable=entry.var)
    entry.grid(padx=2, pady=3)

    lbox = tk.Listbox(frame, width=40, height=15)
    lbox.grid(padx=2, pady=3)

    update_list()
    
    return frame
    
searchframe = search_frame()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Rather than getting rid of the display I refresh it by using 
```
for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
```
at the start of main(), and then rebuilding it. The reason for this is because depending on what the user does the root window will be altered.

Comment: I actually thought about this but my initial implementation was `search_var.trace("w", lambda search_var, lbox: update_list(search_var, lbox))` but i dint get a proper output so i was like nvm, but `*args` does the trick.

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 ~ See what I appended to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: til that you can define functions within functions. I like your code a lot. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 ~ regarding:"I like your code a lot". Thanks, but it isn't very good. All this procedural programming stuff is a big mess. If I was writing this for me, `def search_frame` would be `class SearchFrame`. It would be extremely versatile, dynamic and reusable, and I would never have to write it again, but I could use it in anything. Just like you use `Entry`, `Label` , etc.. in anything.

Comment: I plan on learning classes soon. A bit late for this code but in the future I'll use that instead.